# Add items to list from linq var

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following query:

```
    public class CheckItems
    {
        public String Description { get; set; }
        public String ActualDate { get; set; }
        public String TargetDate { get; set; }
        public String Value { get; set; }
    }



   List<CheckItems>  vendlist = new List<CheckItems>();

   var vnlist = (from up in spcall
               where up.Caption == "Contacted"
                      select new CheckItems
                      {
                          Description = up.Caption,
                          TargetDate = string.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", up.TargetDate),
                          ActualDate = string.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", up.ActualDate),
                          Value = up.Value
                      }).ToList();
```

// Next, when I try to add vnlist to vendlist, I get an error as I cannot add this to the list I get and error saying I have some invalid arguments

```
         vendlist.Add(vnlist);
```

Comment: You can remove the .ToList call.  AddRange takes an enumerable, and it will enumerate it all on its own.  The ToList is making a list, populating it, and the immediately discarding it.  Why waste the time on it.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you need to add any IEnumerable collection of elements to the list you need to use [`AddRange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc.aspx).

```
vendlist.AddRange(vnlist);
```

Comment: Not just an "array" but any IEnumerable.

Answer (score 5):

Or combine them...

```
vendlist.AddRange((from up in spcall
               where up.Caption == "Contacted"
                      select new CheckItems
                      {
                          Description = up.Caption,
                          TargetDate = string.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", up.TargetDate),
                          ActualDate = string.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", up.ActualDate),
                          Value = up.Value
                      }).ToList());
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you try to add a complete list instead of a single CheckItems instance.
I don't have a C# compiler here but maybe AddRange instead of Add works:

```
vendlist.AddRange(vnlist);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one simple way to do this:

```
List<CheckItems>  vendlist = new List<CheckItems>();

var vnlist =    from up in spcall
                where up.Caption == "Contacted"
                select new
                  {
                      up.Caption,
                      up.TargetDate,
                      up.ActualDate,
                      up.Value
                  };

foreach (var item in vnlist)
            {
                CheckItems temp = new CheckItems();
                temp.Description = item.Caption;
                temp.TargetDate = string.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", item.TargetDate);
                temp.ActualDate = string.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", item.ActualDate);
                temp.Value = item.Value;

                vendlist.Add(temp);
            }
```