# how to add more than one result to the list using a linq query

Tags: c#

```
listDates = new List<DateTime>();

var ven = (from Ven in DBCon.VenueSchedules
           select new

           {
               Ven.Date,
               Ven.ScheduleID,

           }).FirstOrDefault();
            listDates.Add(Convert.ToDateTime(ven.Date));
```

this only adds the only the first result of the query , I want it to add all the results of the query

Comment: Instead of .FirstOrDefault use .ToList, to get the list.

Comment: typical 'get my work done' question. 1 min of msdn search would have solved it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add items to list from linq var](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9216207/add-items-to-list-from-linq-var)

Comment: You call `FirstOrDefault()` and then complain *"this only adds the only the first result of the query"*. I have doubts you understand current code or you will understand the answer.

Comment: Just get rid of the `.FirstOrDefault()` call and you should be good.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
listDates = new List<DateTime>();

var ven = (from Ven in DBCon.VenueSchedules
           select new

           {
               Ven.Date,
               Ven.ScheduleID,

           }).ToList();
            listDates.AddRange(ven.Select(v => Convert.ToDateTime(v)).ToList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following :

```
listDates = new List<DateTime>();
var ven = (from Ven in DBCon.VenueSchedules
   select new
   {
      Ven.Date,
      Ven.ScheduleID,
    }).ToList();
listDates.AddRange(ven.Select(item=>Convert.ToDateTime(item.Date)).ToList());
```

Answer (score 0):

You could only select the date, then use `AsEnumerable()` to finish the db request and then use `Select` to convert the result to `DateTime`s and turn the enumeration into a list using `ToList()`:

```
listDates = (from Ven in DBCon.VenueSchedules
             select Ven.Date).AsEnumerable()
            .Select(d => Convert.ToDateTime(d)).ToList();
```